# Cells Labels Not Resizing Until Table Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I'm using this code to resize the labels that maintains the titles of my cells. The problem is that the cells labels are not resizing until I scroll the table. Cells need to disappear to resize their labels correctly. What can I do to get all the cells labels well resized without having to scroll previously?

Thanks for reading.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ExampleTableViewCell *cell = (ExampleTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExampleTableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExampleTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.title.text = [self.test objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    //Calculates the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of the label.
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(200, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [cell.title.text sizeWithFont:cell.title.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:cell.title.lineBreakMode];

    // Adjusts the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = cell.title.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    cell.title.frame = newFrame;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Post the code for delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath..

Comment: There I'm just returning the maximum size of the cells

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found Matt Long's solution really helpful (http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the same code in

`willDisplayCell` method of UItableViewController

Another approach is .... in your ExampleTableViewCell class implement

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
}
```

set your title's frame in above function. It should work

Comment: It works, but only the first time. I'm still having the same problem when I switch back to this view once I have visited it before

Answer (score 0):

you must implement the method heightForRowAtIndexPath and return the height of cell then your problem solved :-)